# Java/Generics: Return a list of extending a type?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

If I have the following:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

public <T extends A> List<T> getList() {
   List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.add(new A());
   return list;
}
```

But I get the error: `add(T) in List cannot be applied to A`

What I would like to do is return a list of Class A or any class extending Class A. Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: If you want to return a list containing instances of A, make your return type `List<A>`. No type variable is needed.

Comment: You define a List<String> and try to add an Object to it.

Comment: Suppose that `A` is `Animal` and `T` is `Dog`. What you're going is creating a `List<Dog>` and then adding an `Animal` to that list. That doesn't work, because an `Animal` is not a `Dog`.

Comment: To put it another way, what are you expecting the static type of `obj.<B>getList().get(0)` to be?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an instance of `A` to a list of type that extends `A`, such as `List<B>`, since `A` isn't a `B` (but visa-versa).